# how to get the most used tags with Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have two entities, "Pin" and "Tag", with a ManyToMany relation.
I want to get a list of tags order by most used to display in a form

here my repository with the method :

```
    public function findPopularTag(){
    return $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  p.id) AS total_pins')
    ->leftJoin('t.listeEpingles', 'p')
    ->groupBy('t.id')
    ->orderBy('total_pins','DESC');


}
```

in my buildForm i use this method to create an entityType :

```
            $builder->add(  'listeTagsDansListeEpingles', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'SharincookRecipesBundle:Tag',
                'required'  =>false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'property' => 'libelle',
                'expanded'=>true,
                'query_builder' => function(TagRepository $repo){
                    return $repo->findPopularTag();
                },


        ));
```

but i have an error : 
**Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given** 
in **vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php at line 224**

Comment: have you added `->getQuery()->getResult()` after `orderBy()` ? in your sample code this is missing

Comment: i can't do that because i have to get a queryBuilder in my buildForm.

Comment: Try this one ` ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  p.id) AS HIDDEN total_pins')` so that ORM will not fetch the result of this column in result set

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!! it works!!! i'am on this problem since five days

Comment: glad i could help +1 for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join and order by in your query builder

```
$tag = $em->getRepository('NamespaceYourBundle:Tag');
$qb = $tag->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  p.id) AS HIDDEN total_pins')
        ->leftJoin('t.pins', 'p');
        ->groupBy('t.id')
        ->orderBy('total_pins','DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it return a list of Pin and i just want a list of tags. because i call the method in a buildform for an entityType

Comment: @sepointes sorry i posted the answer in wrong see my updated answer

Comment: i put your code in a my repository : `public function findPopularTag(){
  return $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  p.id) AS total_pins')
        ->leftJoin('t.listeEpingles', 'p')
        ->groupBy('t.id')
        ->orderBy('total_pins','DESC');


 }`   and i call this method il my entityType but i have an error : **Expected argument of type "object or array", "string" given**

Comment: @sepointes its better if you update your question with required code from your error code it seems the error is related to other than the query